# RestKit mapping to a property only

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, restkit-0.20

I have a `JSON` response as follows:

```
 {
   response : {
        data : {
             subjects : [
                {
                },
                {
                }
             ]
        }
   }
  }
```

and i have a NSManagedObject as follows:

```
@interface Department : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *subjects;

@end
```

I have a department record in `Department` table with id = 1 and name = "Physics". I want to modify this existing department with obtained `subjects` from response JSON data. the subjects field only to be updated rest should be kept same. Would you please tell me the RestKit 0.20 mapping code for this?

**UPDATE**

this is the mapping i performed:

```
NSDictionary *subMappingDict = @{
    @"id": @"id",
    @"sub_name": @"name"
};

RKEntityMapping *subMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Subject" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
[subMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:subMappingDict];
subMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"id"];

RKEntityMapping *deptMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Department" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
[deptMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"subjects" toKeyPath:@"subjects" withMapping:subMapping]];

RKEntityMapping *collegeMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"College" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
[collegeMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"data" toKeyPath:@"department" withMapping:deptMapping]];

NSIndexSet *statusCodes = RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful);
RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:collegeMapping pathPattern:nil keyPath:@"response" statusCodes:statusCodes];
```

I have an existing `College` record which has an existing `Department` record. Here i want to update Department's `subjects` field only by the mapping.

Comment: How are you going to make the request to get this JSON? What mappings / descriptors have you tried? What is you `Subject` entity?

Comment: To get the subjects, will you do a GET using a `Department` instance, and the department `id` is in the URL of the request?

Comment: No. i will send a request with a authentication token only. I wont give any id for department or college.

Comment: Then it will be hard to get RestKit to do it. You may want to get RestKit to map the subjects and then connect the result objects in the success callback.

Comment: if i have id for Department instance, what can i do?

Comment: If its in the URL or the response you can use foreign key mapping. If in the URL you would use routing meta data to extract the id.